# Robot Framework - using User Libraries

Tags: java, python, robotframework

i am facing difficulty when trying to run my tests. Here is what i did :

1. Create a java project with one class which has one method called hello(String name)
2. Exported this as a jar and kept it in the same directory where i keep my test case file.
3. my Test case looks like this.

   - Setting *  * Value *   * Value *   * Value *   * Value *   * Value *

     Library    MyLibrary
   - Variable * * Value *   * Value *   * Value *   * Value *   * Value *

     - Test Case *   * Action *  * Argument *    * Argument *    * Argument *    * Argument *
       MyTest
                 hello           World
     - Keyword * * Action *  * Argument *    * Argument *    * Argument *    * Argument *

I always get the following error :

Error in file 'C:\Users\yahiya\Desktop\robot-practice\testcase_template.tsv' in table 'Setting': Importing test library 'MyLibrary' failed: ImportError: No module named MyLibrary

I have configured Pythopath in the system variables in my windows machine.

Please let me know what am i doing wrong here.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try to put your Library into this folder:

...YourPythonFolder\Lib\site-packages\

or, if this doesn't work, make in the folder "site-packages" folder with the name "MyLibrary" and put your library there.

This should work.

Answer (score 0):

There might a problem with how you import your library. I don't have much experience with Java libraries but you need to provide the whole name, including the package name, when importing a library.

[Read more](http://robotframework.googlecode.com/svn/tags/robotframework-2.1/doc/userguide/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#test-library-names) in the guide.