# RED Editor - When adding Java Library

Tags: robotframework

I'm using RED editor for my automation. I see an indication next to the Add Java Library button. Mouse hovering this, stated as "Project is configured to use Jython interpreter, but jython is needed for Java libraries".

What does it mean? The java project should have jython libary included? Am I missing something?.

[image]

Comment: Jython is needed when using Java libraries. This is configured in the General tab of your Project or in the Settings of RED/Eclipse.

Comment: I did reference Jython in RED General tab for Robot framework. So it doesn't mean that i have to integrate jython into my java project when creating a library, Am i right?

Comment: Can you have a look at this [guide](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42384822/it-errors-when-specifying-the-user-defined-java-library-into-red-robot-framework/42402090#42402090) and see if this solves your problem?

Comment: Thank You Kootstra! I'm clear enough on this now.

Answer (score 0):

As highlighted in the comment, I think you will find that if you follow the steps in my response to [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42384822/it-errors-when-specifying-the-user-defined-java-library-into-red-robot-framework/42402090#42402090), that you will end up with a correctly configured RED project.

As for the message:

> "Project is configured to use Jython interpreter, but Jython is needed
>   for Java libraries"

This is also present in a working Jython setup. So I wouldn't worry about it. To me this looks like a RED defect.